# How can I get last 1 min data from Rabbit MQ without pulling

Tags: rabbitmq

**I want to get last 1 min data from Rabbitmq.**

*I have a scenario where I want to get last 1 minute data from rabbit mq and that should not be remove from queue.*

I can also use pull mechanism but when we pull data from rabbitmq that remove from queue so that is possible in my case.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can see this thread:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/eRkNnKqmSEY

Anyway you can't make a query. If you don't want "consume" your messages you can create an exchange and bind two queues with the same message, use one for read "the last one minute, and consume all messages" and the other one maintains the messages.

hope it helps